# Parallel.ForEach takes more time than expected

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, parallel-processing, threadpool

Here the code on this concern:

```
while (true)
{
    Console.WriteLine("start " + DateTime.Now);
    ParallelOptions options = new ParallelOptions();
    options.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = -1;                
    Parallel.ForEach(hosts, item =>
    {
        using (Ping ping = new Ping())
        {
            PingReply pingReply = ping.Send(item.Value, 2000);  // timeout is 2 secs
            App.dict[item.Key].lastConnectTry = new KeyValuePair<bool, DateTime>((pingReply.Status == IPStatus.Success), DateTime.Now);
        }
    });        
    Console.WriteLine("end " + DateTime.Now);
    Thread.Sleep(15000);
}
```

But, then I run that app it gives slightly different results:

```
start 27.04.2012 10:12:32
end 27.04.2012 10:12:42
// it took 10 seconds
start 27.04.2012 10:12:57
end 27.04.2012 10:13:02
// this took 5 secs
start 27.04.2012 10:13:17
end 27.04.2012 10:13:22
//   5 secs
start 27.04.2012 10:13:37
end 27.04.2012 10:13:42
// 5 secs
start 27.04.2012 10:13:57
end 27.04.2012 10:14:01
start 27.04.2012 10:14:16
end 27.04.2012 10:14:19
start 27.04.2012 10:14:34
end 27.04.2012 10:14:36
start 27.04.2012 10:14:51
end 27.04.2012 10:14:54
start 27.04.2012 10:15:09
end 27.04.2012 10:15:11
start 27.04.2012 10:15:26
end 27.04.2012 10:15:29
start 27.04.2012 10:15:44
end 27.04.2012 10:15:46
start 27.04.2012 10:16:01
end 27.04.2012 10:16:06
start 27.04.2012 10:16:21
end 27.04.2012 10:16:24
start 27.04.2012 10:16:39
end 27.04.2012 10:16:41
start 27.04.2012 10:16:56
end 27.04.2012 10:16:59
start 27.04.2012 10:17:14
end 27.04.2012 10:17:16
```

Seems like it takes some time to bootstrap the threads, creating them and then Parallel execution time will arranged correctly.

So the question is why it takes more than 2 secs to handle all processing and how can I avoid it by bootstrap the threads before processing?

**Update:**

This loop is placed in separate background thread.

Comment: How many elements in `hosts`, and how many cores do you have? And what do you mean by "boostrapping" the threads?

Comment: hosts are filled by 22 elements. Two cores. "Bootstrapping" means kinda creating threads in threadpool that being used. I'm not so clear about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, threadpool needs to grow number of threads based on load (unrelated to Parallel.ForEach).

Check [Parallel.ForEach not spinning up new threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1861548/parallel-foreach-not-spinning-up-new-threads) and [Parallel.Foreach spawning way too many threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2002864/parallel-foreach-spawning-way-too-many-threads) for some background.

Comment: So how can I make this loop always use concrete count of threads?

Comment: I don't think so, you can restrict max, but otherwise ForEach and ThreadPool will try to adjust to your load.

Comment: You can try to pre-grow the threadpool (ThreadPool.SetMinThreads) as discussed http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9248199/threadpool-behaviour-not-growing-from-minimum-size

Comment: Thanks, Alexei! Pre-growing the threadpool nicely helped out. Spasibo, Alexei!

Answer (score 1):

You're not actually passing your parallel options through, see here:

```
ParallelOptions options = new ParallelOptions();
options.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = -1;                
Parallel.ForEach(hosts, options, item => // note options passed through here
      // etc
```

If this isn't creating enough, you can increase the threadpool:

`System.Threading.ThreadPool.SetMinThreads`
`System.Threading.ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads`

But note that really unless you know you're going to get improvements I wouldn't touch this. Since you're doing a `Ping` in your task code, this could be the thing adding the variability between each run.

Comment: It gives the same result. Max threads is setted to huge value so there is no any issues.